# Python file path and name retrieval

Tags: python, tkinter, save, filepath

Alright so I've made a save as button in python and was wondering how do I retrieve the file path from where it was saved.  I also was wondering if the name is changed during saving how to know what that is. If I try to call the file name in a different .py file I receive a error code. Code for the button is below

Thanks

```
import tkinter, tkinter.constants, tkinter.filedialog

class tkFile(tkinter.Frame):

    def __init__(self, root):

        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        button_opt = {'fill': tkinter.constants.BOTH, 'padx': 5, 'pady': 5}
        tkinter.Button(self, text='Save As',command=self.asksaveasfilename).pack(**button_opt)

        self.file_opt = options = {}
        options['filetypes'] = [('all files', '.*'), ('csv files', '.csv')]
        options['initialfile'] = 'data.csv'
        options['parent'] = root

    def asksaveasfilename(self):
        filename = tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(**self.file_opt)

        if filename:
            return open(filename, 'w')

if __name__=='__main__':
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    tkFile(root).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

The code that I want to call the name into is below. Specifically I'm looking to call the name from the save as button to a different file. The error code states self in undefined.

```
name = savePathButton.tkFile.asksaveasfilename(self)

name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: This question is a bit confusing. You're given the filename, which  you use to open the file. Why don't you just save it for when you need it later?

Comment: I'm having difficulties returning the filename when used later in the program. This is more a create a file button than a save as button.

Comment: What is it you are trying to do here? `filename = tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(**self.file_opt)` gives you the `filename` the user wants to save to. Why the use of `return open(filename, 'w')`? Why not just `return filename` and then in a later function call `with open(filename, 'w')` to write open/create and write to file?

Comment: still when i return the filename and try to call it later what do i put as the variable instead of self.  If i put self It says its undefined making me not be able to call the file name.

Answer (score 0):

You can `import os`, and use `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` to retrieve the file location.

For the actual file name, you could use `os.listdir(os.getcwd())` which would return a list of file names within the directory.